# What's the proper way to do this in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

So I've got two records from Model, a and b. I want to do this:

```
def do_codependant_stuff(a,b)
    a.attribute += b.attribute2
    b.attribute = b.stuff+a.stuff
end
```

I keep hearing fat model, skinny controller, and no business logic in views, so I've put this in my Model model. Based on what a user clicks in one of my views, I want to call do_codependant_stuff(a, b) or do_codependant_stuff(b,a).

I've been just using the basic crud controller actions up to this point, and I'm not quite sure how to make this happen. Do I add this logic to my ModelController update action? Because it's technically updating them, just in a more specific way. Or make another action in the controller? How do I call it/set it up? Most of the default new, update etc are somehow called behind the scenes based on their respective views.

And is updating two things at a time bad practice? Should I split the do_codependant_stuff method into two instance methods and call them on each record with the other as a parameter?

Thanks for reading.

Edit:
Alright, real world code. I'm displaying on the home page of my app two pictures. The user selects the one they like most. The ratings of these pictures change based on a chess ranking algorithm. This is the relevant section of my picture class.

```
 class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   ...
        def expected_first_beats_second(picture first, picture second)
            1/(1+10**((second.rating-first.rating)/400))
        end
        def first_beat_second(picA,picB)
            Ea = expected_first_beats_second(picA,picB)
            picA.rating += 50*(1-Ea)
            picB.rating += 50*(-(1-Ea))

        end
    end
```

The partial I'm using for the view just displays two pictures at random so far with

```
<% picA = Picture.offset(rand(Picture.count)).first %>
<% picB = Picture.offset(rand(Picture.count)).first %>

<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-5">
        <%= image_tag picA.url, :class => "thumbnail" %>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-5">
        <%= image_tag picB.url, :class => "thumbnail" %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to somehow link the onclick of those images to the method in the model.

Comment: It seems like it'd be a lot less hassle if I could just call do_codependant_stuff straight from my view. If someone could also explain why it's important not to do that, I'd appreciate it

Comment: I'd guess because the controller is supposed to control access to the model? So a security thing? Possibly also an code organizational thing?

Comment: This would be a lot easier to answer with a real-world example rather than your hypothetical code. Firstly, there's a chance you're conceptually doing something unusual which could be better implemented in another way. Secondly, a hypothetical question gets a hypothetical answer, which will probably be useless for you. Real code please.

Comment: Sorry - have been AFK for the weekend. Glad you got the answer you needed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code to get you started. Note the comments, they're ruby and rails best practices

Controller:

```
class PC < AC
  ...
  def compare
    # count query once, save the number
    count = Picture.count
    @pic_a = Picture.offset(rand(count)).first
    @pic_b = Picture.offset(rand(count)).first
  end

  def compare_submit
    # Note variables are snake cased, not camel cased
    pic_a = Picture.find(params[:winner_id])
    pic_b = Picture.find(params[:loser_id])
    pic_a.beats(pic_b)
    redirect to compare_pictures_path # Or wherever
  end
  ...
end
```

Any sort of querying should be done in the controller or model. You essentially should never directly access a model in your view. At this point your view has access to the instance variables set in the controller: `@pic_a` and `@pic_b`

View:

```
<%= link_to compare_submit_pictures_path(winner_id: @pic_a.id, loser_id: @pic_b.id) do %>
  <%= image_tag @pic_a.url, :class => "thumbnail" %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to compare_submit_pictures_path(winner_id: @pic_b.id, loser_id: @pic_a.id) do %>
  <%= image_tag @pic_b.url, :class => "thumbnail" %>
<% end %>
```

So we just linked to a new path (see routes below) that will pass two parameters: `winner_id` and `loser_id` so whichever picture the user clicks on you'll know which one they chose and which one they didn't choose.

Model:

```
class Picture < AR::Base
  # Method arguments don't need a type declaration
  def beats(loser)
    # Always lowercase variables
    ea = 1/(1+10**((loser.rating-self.rating)/400))
    self.rating += 50*(1-ea)
    loser.rating += 50*(-(1-ea))
    self.save
    loser.save       
  end
end
```

This explicitly uses `self` for clarity, which isn't necessary. Calling `save` or `rating = ...` implicitly calls it on self since we're in the context of an instance method on the picture Model.

Routes:

```
resource :pictures do
  collection do
    get :compare
    get :compare_submit
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Couple questions, I thought you have to write self.beats for an instance method declaration, what am I missing? Also, why should I combine the two methods in the model? Finally, having compare as a page of it's own, does that mean I can't do the comparison on the home page? Or I guess I could just make that the new root path right?

Comment: And I guess the view wouldn't be a partial anymore, it's its own page? compare.html.erb under pictures?

Comment: Also, on the routes bit, do I need to add get: before compare, and/or post before :compare_submit?

Comment: @NathanTempelman instance method declarations do not use self. Defining `def self.foo; end` in a class creates a class method. And you can break up the model methods however you want, but if the logic is not reused and that simple (5 readable lines) I see no reason to have multiple methods. I highly recommend going through some basic rails tutorials for your other questions. They've all been answered many, many times! Lastly, I declared the routes wrong, that's updated.

Comment: Yeah I got it working. Also apparently you can't redirect to xxx_path, it's gotta be xxx_url.

Comment: but thank you so much, it finally clicked in my head. All the tutorials I've been going through are so verbose and they all use scaffolding or the default create update whatevers, and they rarely explain the magic going on behind the scenes. I think I'm beginning to get MVC now, so thanks again for that.

Comment: @NathanTempelman great, glad it helped. Scaffolding really becomes helpful when you know enough to build it yourself, it just saves you a bunch of time. Otherwise it is awfully magical and mysterious. And thanks for the redirect tip, apparently that's changed since rails 3